# although method exists but I still receive the error :"Could not find method methodName(View) in a parent or ancestor Context"

Tags: android

There are lots of similar questions in SO about this, but in all of them the error is because of a typo, or type/number of arguments of the method, or the method is in a wrong place which non applies for my problem.

I have an `ImageButton` in my xml which is iterated in a `ListView` which is in a `Fragment`

I have added `android:onClick="methodName"` to it.

and the method exists in the activity of the fragment:

```
fun methodName(v: View)
{
    //some code
}
```

and editor confirms that (in XML no error is shown for onClick) and the method shows that there is a reference to it. however after the application runs, I get the error:

> Could not find method methodName(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'item_id'

**Update**:
I tried cleaning and rebuilding project and didn't work. Restarting Android Studio didn't work either.

I removed my method, and in the xml file clicked on "create onClick event hadler" and it recreated the method, but still getting the same error.

Comment: `ImageButton` or `ImageView` ?

Comment: Oh yes, its an ImageButton

Comment: is your ImageButton part of the row of your ListView?

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you using ListView?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, it is in a row of my listview

Answer (score 0):

Try these

1) Try to rename your method, don't keep it too generic like onClick()

2) If you have @override annotation over it, remove it.

3) Try making method public once.

Comment: it has a very unique name however I renamed it (doesn't work), it is already public and it is not override, yet it does not work

Comment: Can you also try changing ImageButton to ImageView for now, because ImageButton has been quite buggy in past, and had issues, Just try once?